# AndroidAnnotations how to add init code after onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

If I have an activity defined as:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_login)
public class LoginActivity extends Activity
```

This will create the onCreate() method for me, but I have extra init code that I want to go after the onCreate method, how should I do this?  I could create my own onCreate method and use an empty @EActivity, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [@AfterViews](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views#afterviews) annotation to define your own initialization code:

```
@AfterViews
protected void init() {
    // your custom code
}
```