# Android Annotations - setContentView called last

Tags: android, android-activity, android-annotations, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I have a basic question. In the android annotations library, it creates activities with *, which in turn extend the original activity.
public final class HubActivity*
    extends HubActivity
    implements HasViews, OnViewChangedListener
{

```
private final OnViewChangedNotifier onViewChangedNotifier_ = new OnViewChangedNotifier();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    OnViewChangedNotifier previousNotifier = OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(onViewChangedNotifier_);
    init_(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(previousNotifier);
    setContentView(layout.activity_hub);
}
```

if you see the last statement is the setContentView in onCreate method. Additionally, it calls the super.onCreate() method prior to that. Now, if I have written some code in the Activity onCreate method which is dependent on the view elements, it will not work, would it? How do we tackle this? Any design practices I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out.
Thanks to the question -
[AndroidAnnotations how to add init code after onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718266/androidannotations-how-to-add-init-code-after-oncreate)

The UI elements initialization and other wirings apart from the view binding should be done in the init method with an @AfterViews annotation

```
@AfterViews
protected void init() {
    // your custom code
}
```

Comment: Indeed, please refer to the [doc](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views).

Comment: @3mpty: no, injected views are not yet available in `@AfterInject` annotated methods, only in `@AfterViews` annotated methods. `@AfterInject` can be used for injected beans, prefs, rest, etc.

Comment: Yes, it was shorthand. Sorry about that. I mean that you can also init your code there, I didn't meant Views. Usually I'm using @AfterInject also when I need to init something that is not require Views or something that I need init before views.

Comment: Don't forget to select your answer as the correct answer.